# Wooden fence requires post on conblock - Solution required

Tags: wood, brick, fence, post, fixings

I am building a fence in my back garden, in Indonesia.

(2.8m W) panels to be 80cm tall. 2 post to be secured to wall (easy part) and two posts to be secured onto conblock, my issue is securing the posts to the conblock.

Initially I was going to just put a little concrete underneath the posts (because I'm not allowed to removed the blocks) and then secure the cross members to the posts....screw on panels....Done.

Then I thought about the wind and kids pushing or playing with the fence and thought the post would fail and fence falls over.

I want to know if I can drill into the conblock and secure with bolts/screws & plugs....Setting rebar into it isn't an option here.

Just not sure if I can secure to conblock and be happy it stays there.

Comment: Photos would help

Comment: What exactly is "conblock"? Presumably it's a concatenation of "concrete" & "block", but in your context, does it refer to a specific type of manufactured product, or is it just "big lump of solid concrete"?

Comment: Usually a bolt is installed into concrete as it's poured, then a post-base is attached to the bolt, then the post is set into the post-base. However, it seems that it's too late to do it that way for you, so It sounds like drilling and epoxying a rod/bolt of some sort would be a good idea. However, we'll need good pics of this "conblock" so _we_ can see what _you_ see. Otherwise, we're just making random guesses and that won't help you much.

Comment: Also, it's recommended that you check with local building regulators to see if they have anything to say. AIUI, regulations are rather loose in Indonesia compared to the USA, but it's worth asking.

Comment: Shall sort pics out later. The conblock is a not so compacted concrete block and they're hexagonal shape, laid down on the ground to form paving over land. About 12sq m. For regulations etc, in Indonesia, it doesn't matter on my own land unless I'm building more than 1 floor

Answer (score 1):

Making the assumption that "conblock" is some form of concrete block, there are two possible ways to do this that come to mind, both of which involve drilling into the concrete.

One method is to set the post beside the concrete block wall, and drill to secure it against the wall - if the wall is at least 1/3 of the total post length high, that's a very secure mounting.

The other is to drill into the top of the wall to secure some sort of bracket to secure the post to - the security of the mounting depends on the design of the bracket as well as the connection to the wall.

There are likely other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, the post being mounted to the wall is not the issue. The conblock (you're right about a concrete block, just what they're called here) is the floor, they're hexagonol blocks.
I spoke to a local buoder here, he confirmed to treat it like a concrete block.... Drill and plug the secure with bolt or decent sized fixing screw.